# How to add tableview controler inside pageview controler

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, ios8.1

I am implementing a tableview controller inside a pageview controller. For the first time it is loading properly, but when I try move on the previous / next page the view becomes Blank.

can any one suggest me how to load a tableview controller inside a pageview controller.

I am creating a form based application , so in a tableview there can be textfield, textview , imageview etc. Every thing works fine for first time only, next time only blank screen shows.

Please suggest me some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Container view and then navigate to different view controller on page index changes